# Launch screen via custom url for iPhone 5

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, iphone-5, default.png

According to the Apple [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html), I can use different launch images when my app is launched via a custom url scheme. I have been able to implement this for the 3.5" standard and retina images.

I am supposed to use

```
<basename>-<url_scheme><scale_modifier><device_modifier>.png
```

which yields Default.png -> default-customURL.png
and Default@2x.png -> Default-customURL@2x.png

but I can't quite get it right for

Default-568h@2x.png -> ???

How am I supposed to format this file name?

Comment: I was referring to the Default.png images - in the linked document they are discussed under the heading "App Launch (Default) Images". Of course I figured it out as soon as I had asked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct format is:

```
Default-customURL-568h@2x.png
Default-customURL-667h@2x.png
Default-customURL-756h@3x.png
```

...for 4", 4.7" and 5.5" Retina displays